# $V = W\oplus W^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a vector subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $k:V\times V\to \mathbb{C}$ be a nondegenerate bilinear form such that $k_{|W\times W}$ is also nondegenerate. Define $W^{\perp} = \{x\in V| k(x,y) = 0\;\forall y\in W\}$. I want to understand why dim $V$ = dim $W$ + dim $W^{\perp}$.

If we regard $k: W\to V^*$, then Ker $k = 0$ which means dim Im $k$ = dim $W$. Thus elements of Im $k$ must be linear forms on $V$ that maps $W^\perp$ to $0$, which has dimension dim $V$ - dim $W^{\perp}$.  Thus dim $W \le $ dim $V$ - dim $W^\perp$. I want equality, which means I need to show for any $\phi\in V^*$ such that $\phi(W^\perp) =0$ there is a $y\in W$ such that $\phi = k(y,\cdot)$, which I need help with.

Comment: Assume it doesn't. Pick a vector not in there. Gram-Schmidt it. Show that it must be nonzero and is in the orthogonal complement.

Comment: To show $\dim V = \dim W + \dim W^\perp$, actually the fact that $k$ is nondegenerate suffices. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93107/96384. You need the nondegeneracy of the restricted form only to show $W \cap W^\perp = \{0\}$, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1295105/96384 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3550381/96384.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $W\to W^\ast$ defined by the bilinear form is injective, hence surjective, so $V\to W^\ast$ is also surjective, and it has kernel $W^\perp$.

Answer (score 1):

Pick an orthonormal basis $(v_i)$ of $W$ and an orthonormal basis $(w_i)$ of $W^{\perp}$. Then $y = \sum \phi(v_i) v_i \in W$ satisfies the requirement since $k(y, v_i) = \phi(v_i)$ and $k(y, w_i) = 0$ by orthogonality of $W$ and $W^{\perp}$.