# If a Bilinear Form is Non-Degenerate on a Subspace $W$, then $V=W\oplus W^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form

$\newcommand{\range}{\text{image}}\newcommand{\ann}{\text{Ann}}\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}$

> **Problem:** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $f$ be a *symmetric* bilinear form on $V$.
>   Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$.
>   If $f$ is non-degenerate on $W$, then $V=W\oplus W^\perp$.

Below I provide a proof of this.
***My problem*** is that my proof doesn't seem to make use of the fact that $f$ is symmetric.
Is the above theorem also true if we strike out the word symmetric? If yes, then one may not read my proof and just leave a comment. *If not then can one check where have I used the symmetry of $f$ in the argument?*

---

**Definitions and Notations:**

Given a bilinear form $f$ on a (finite dimensional) vector space $V$, we define $R_f:V\to V^*$ as $(R_fv)(u)=f(u, v)$ for all $u, v\in V$.
Clearly $R_f$ is a linear map.

For a subspace $W$ of $V$, we write $f|W$ to denotes the restriciton of $f$ to $W\times W$. It can be seen that $f|W$ is a bilinear form on $W$.
We define $W^\perp$ as $\set{v\in V: f(w, v)=0 \ for \ all \ w\in W}$.
Also, we write $\ann W$ to denote the annihilator of $W$.

We say that $f$ is **non-degenerate** on a subspace $W$ of $V$ is $R_{f|W}:W\to W^*$ has rank $\dim W$.

---

**The Purported Proof:**

It is clear that $f$ is non-degenerate on $W$ if and only if $W\cap W^\perp=\set{0}$.
So it suffices to show that $\dim W+\dim W^{\perp}=\dim V$.
To this end, first we note the simple fact that given $v\in V$ we have
\begin{equation*}
v\in W^\perp\ \iff\ R_fv\in \ann W
\tag{1}
\end{equation*}

Let $\pi:V^*\to V^*/\ann W$ be the canonical projection map and conider the liner map $\pi\circ R_f:V\to V^*/\ann W$.

By the Rank-Nullity Theorem we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dim V &=& \dim \ker (\pi\circ R_f) + \dim \range(\pi\circ R_f)\\
\\
&\leq& \dim \ker (\pi\circ R_f) + \dim (V^*/\ann W)\\
\\
&=& \dim \ker (\pi\circ R_f) + \dim W
\end{array}
$$

Note that from (1) we know that $\ker (\pi\circ R_f)=W^\perp$.
Therefore $\dim V\leq \dim W^\perp+\dim W$.
But since $W\cap W^\perp=\set{0}$, we also have $\dim V\geq \dim W+\dim W^\perp$.
So we must have $\dim V=\dim W+\dim W^\perp$ and we are done.

---

Comment: Yes, symmetry of the bilinear form is irrelevant. For the reason your proof exposes.

Comment: Thank you. I asked this because in Hoffman and Kunze's book on Linear Algebra, there is an exercise which asks to prove it but provides symmetry of the form in the hypothesis.

Comment: Well, there's one thing I missed due to it being before my morning tea: without symmetry, you generally have ${}^\perp W \neq W^\perp$, the left and right "orthogonal complement"s differ. But, if a bilinear form is non-degenerate on $W$, then both, $W^\perp$ and ${}^\perp W$ are (algebraic) complements of $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For symmetric or skew-symmetric forms $(u,v)=0 \implies (v,u) = 0$. But you are right, the statement does not need any of them, just decide what $\perp$  means. The nice thing is that if non-degeneracy holds for one map, it holds for the flip one ( since, if a matrix is nonsingular, then its transpose also is). Here is a quick proof to have in your toolbox ( from Milnor&Husemoller's book Symmetric bilinear forms).

Take $v \in V$. The map $W \to F$, $u \mapsto (u,v) $ is a linear functional so it must be the dot product with a unique $w$ from $W$. Hence we have $v = w + (v - w)= w + w'$.  Note that $w' \in W^{\perp}$.

Comment: That's great. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If $W$ contains a null vector, the statement (that the intersection of a subspace and it complement is trivial) is false.  For example, a nondegenerate real quadratic form that is indefinite contains contains nonzero vectors that are null.  If such a vector is in $W$, it will be in the intersection with the complement.

Comment: This is not true. Take the $2$-dimensional hyperbolic space (quadratic form $x^2-y^2$) with "null" vector $(1,1)$. If you take as $W$ the space spanned by $w$, then the restriction of the form to $W$ degenerates, so the theorem does not apply. But if you take the whole space as $W$, then its orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$, and does not contain $w$.